# $C$ is a bounded set. $C = \{a + b : a \in A, b \in B\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonempty bounded sets of real numbers. (A set is bounded if it is both bounded above and bounded below.) Let $C = \{a + b : a \in A, b \in B\}$. Show that $C$ is a bounded set and that
$\sup C =\sup A + \sup B$ and $\inf C =\inf A + \inf B$.

I tried to use order properties but get stuck and can't get anywhere. I understand $a+b$ acts as an ordered field , so by using these properties there is a way to prove this. But I can't get anywhere.

Comment: I tried to use order properties but get stuck and can't get any Far. I understand a+b acts as an orders field , so by using these properties there is a way to proof this. But can't get anywhere. Need a at least a first step. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the definition of a supremum?  Suppose that $\alpha = \sup A$ and $\beta = \sup B$.  How can you show that $\alpha + \beta$ satisfies the definition of $\sup C$?

Your definition should be something like

> $\alpha$ is equal to $\sup(A)$ if $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$ and if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an element $a \in A$ such that $\alpha - \epsilon < a$.

How do we know that $\alpha + \beta$ is an upper bound of $C$?  Given an $\epsilon > 0$, how can you guarantee a $c \in C$ such that $\alpha + \beta - \epsilon < c$?