# Proof bounded sets.

Tags: real-analysis

Let A and B be two nonempty bounded sets of real numbers. (A set is bounded if it is both bounded above and bounded below.) Let C = {a + b : a ∈ A, b ∈ B}. Show that C is a bounded set and that
supC =supA+supB and infC =infA+infB.

Still have been struggling and no results...

Comment: it's very easy, it's a matter of the application of the definition, just do another try and tell me where you are get stacked so i can help

Comment: I do not know where to begin... I understand how to show for just a set, but that + is confusing me. I'm just learning to write proof .... Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you are welcome, for the first question, you have to translate the meaning of bounded set in the real line.

Comment: a set $A$ is bounded $\leftrightarrow$ $\exists m, M\in {\mathbb R}$ such that $\forall x\in A$ $m<x<M$

Comment: That I understand , but how the a+b set Supremum is equal to supA+supB. I just don't seem to understand how to approach that...

Comment: you can pove that $\sup C\leq \sup A +\sup b$ and  $\sup C\geq \sup A +\sup b$

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925384/c-is-a-bounded-set-c-a-b-a-in-a-b-in-b

Comment: Let me try, I think you got me in the right track.

Comment: do you what the answer?

Comment: Yes that would be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $A$ and $B$ are bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete then there exist $\hat{a} = \sup{A}\ $ and $\ \hat{b} = \sup{B}$. Take any $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Then by definition of supremum we have that

$$a\leq \sup{A} \quad \text{and} \quad   b\leq \sup{B}$$

It follows that $a+b\leq \sup{A} + \sup{B}$. Then $C$ is bounded by $\hat{c}:=\sup{A}+\sup{B}$.

Now take any $\epsilon >0$. By definition of supremum we have that there exist $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ such that

$$\sup{A} - \frac{\epsilon}{2} < x  \quad \text{and}\quad  \sup{B} - \frac{\epsilon}{2} < y$$

then there exists $x+y \in C$ such that $\sup{A} + \sup{B} - \epsilon < x+y$

That tells us that $\hat{c} = \sup{C}$ by definition of supremum.

It is up to you to prove $\inf{C}$.

Comment: Have an upvote here instead (I agree with Tool)